# Why does nuclear waste contain plutonium?

Tags: nuclear-chemistry

According to [this page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor-grade_plutonium):

> Reactor-grade plutonium (RGPu) is the isotopic grade of plutonium that is found in spent nuclear fuel after the uranium-235 primary fuel that a nuclear power reactor uses has burnt up.

Since plutonium is not found naturally, how does it end up at nuclear waste from nuclear fission reactors?

Comment: Because that is the way how 239Pu is created. ( 238U + n ->  239U -> 239Np -> 239Pu ). What is the desired intermediate product in 239Pu production, is a waste in 235U fission based power plants.

Comment: @z1273 Thanks! Also, the tour and help center links are for the biology stackexchange :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-239)

> The fissioning of an atom of uranium-235 in the reactor of a nuclear
> power plant produces two to three neutrons, and these neutrons can be
> absorbed by uranium-238 to produce plutonium-239 and other isotopes.
> Plutonium-239 can also absorb neutrons and fission along with the
> uranium-235 in a reactor.

[image]

As noted by @IanBush, Pu-239 has a half-life of 24110 years and Pu-240 has a half-life of 6560 years, so they will stay as it is for years before fissioning to any other isotopes.

Comment: It's worth nothing Pu-239 has a half life of ~24,000 years, and Pu-240 ~6500 years, so once they are produced by the above mechanism they are going to hang around for a while, and not just disappear in minutes